# Deleting unused images in drawable folder messes up position of images in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I use a listview that shows an imageview, textview1, textview2, and a checkbox. The data comes from an arraylist:

```
if(arrayList==null) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            arrayList.add(new Country(R.drawable.picaed, Txtshort1, txtlong1, false));
            arrayList.add(new Country(R.drawable.picafn, Txtshort2, txtlong2, false));
            arrayList.add(new Country(R.drawable.picall, Txtshort3, txtlong3, false));
etc.
}
```

In my adapter, I use this code to set the images, texts and checked status:

```
image.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImage());

currency.setText(getItem(position).getCurrency());

country.setText(getItem(position).getCountry());

favourites.setChecked(getItem(position).getFavourites());
```

Everything works just fine, but now I deleted some unused images from the drawable folder in my project (images were completely unrelated to the images used in the arraylist) and suddenly the position of the Images shown in the listview are messed up.

[Thats how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISo0.png)

[Thats how it looks like after deleting the unrelated drawables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lNpC.png)

As you can see, the texts are still in order, but the images are totaly screwed up. Has anyone experienced a similar problem before and can guide me in the right direction?

I tried to find an answer here, but I don't even know where to start / where the problem could be...

Comment: Perhaps try a Clean and Rebuild?

Comment: Hmm, tried to clean and rebuild the project, but the result is still the same. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the device works - probably because arrayList is null again? However, it seems a little unpracticle to expect the user to uninstall and reinstall the app every time I add or delete some random images in the app...